# println() changes values of variables

Tags: serial, arduino-due

I have a function which returns a float value. 
I want to see what value is returned so I print it just before the return statement. 
Surprisingly, the value is `0` (it shouldn't be `0`).

When I want to debug the function and print more things, the value is correct. I do not change anything, I just add a couple of `printl()`.

Let's say:

```cpp
float func() {
  float a = some math calculation;

  some easy math
  Serial.println(a); 
  some easy math
  Serial.println(a);

  Serial.println(a);
  return a;
}
```

If I comment out `println()` lines, I get `0`, which is a wrong value.
If the lines stay uncommented, I get a correct value.

Does anyone have idea why?

I use Arduino Due.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed us the *actual* code we might be able to help you...

Comment: Please post a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not a [snippet](http://snippets-r-us.com/). Perhaps you are dividing by zero? That's "easy math" to do. :)

Comment: Thank you Nick :) 
I used millis() to calculate time and then I divided by the time step. After I changed to micros() everything is as it should be. I think serial printing added necessary time to make the time step not null.

Comment: Can you still post the minimal complete verifiable examples so that others can benefit from your question? They will benefit in two ways 1) an example of why prints can make a difference - especially where timing is important and 2) why it is important to post a complete example to enable when asking a question (a big problem on this site).

Comment: I would suggest adding the "complete example" as a second code block prefixed by "edit - complete code block". Or, simply answer your own question and put the "complete code" in your answer.